# Using strong delegate for initial ViewController in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

My initial `GameViewController` has a delegate property of a `GameDelegate`. I'm setting this property in the `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //Set initial view controller
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    if let window = window {
        let gameTracker = GameTracker()
        let gameViewController = GameViewController()
        gameViewController.delegate = gameTracker
        window.rootViewController = gameViewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    return true
}
```

This only works since my delegate is strong:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController{

        var delegate: GameDelegate?

        var gameScore: GameScore {
            return (delegate!.gameScore)
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }
    }
```

Using a weak delegate will cause the App to crash since delegate will be nil after the `GameViewController` is presented.

My question is: Is this approach safe, and if not, how should it be done? I've read about delegates and it's recommend to keep it as a weak var to prevent a retain cycle. I'm not using Storyboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring the `gameTracker` in a function, rather than as a class-level variable. The `AppDelegate`'s reference to it is released immediately when the function exits, leaving your `GameViewController` with the only reference to it.

The way to solve this is to declare `gameTracker` as a class-level variable in your `AppDelegate`:

```
var gameTracker: GameTracker?
```

You need to declare it as an optional, since you only want to instantiate it when your `if` condition is met:

```
if let window = window {
    self.gameTracker = GameTracker()
    let gameViewController = GameViewController()
    gameViewController.delegate = self.gameTracker
    window.rootViewController = gameViewController
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

If you do this, you will be able to declare your `delegate` as `weak` in your `GameViewController`.

Comment: Great explanation, this makes sense since I indeed counted 2 references from ARC. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Safe approach is using weak delegate. If you handle nil then it shouldn't be a problem.

```
weak var delegate: GameDelegate?

var gameScore: GameScore? {
    return delegate?.gameScore
}
```

Do you intent on calling 'delegate' when 'gameScore' changes? If you want to save 'gameScore' and as well as return 'delegate' then you should use property observer.

```
var gameScore: GameScore {
    didSet {
        delegate?.gameScore
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the exact reason I'm using a strong delegate instead of a weak one. The computed properties need to call the delegate.